# Delete an item from the listview and refresh it on a button click in each row

Tags: android, listview

Hi a am struggling with this part. I want to simply delete an item from the listview when the button on that row is clicked.

I have tried

```
holder.button.setText("End");
holder.button.setTag(position);
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
        app_details.remove(index.intValue());
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
});
```

But it's behavior is unpredictable I mean when click on the button on a row it delete the another item from the listview.

Any one have some idea?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of ListAdapter are you using?

Comment: using custom adapter class which extends `BaseAdapter`

Comment: What value do you set for tag to each view?

Comment: Also use notifyDataSetChanged() for modification of underlying data(in your case, app_details). Use notifyDataSetInvalidated() when underlying data is no longer valid or available(in your case, on removing all items in app_details).

Comment: position of the item clicked. above code is in `getView` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem & finally get rid out of it. Have to tried 
holder.button.setOnItemClickListener Follow the steps to do what you want:

1. Implement  `OnItemClickListener` in your current activity class.
2. set button which delete item from list view to `setOnClickListener`.
3. Set list view to `setOnItemClickListener`  listener in your anonymous inner class (e.g., in `OnClickListener`).
4. `notifyDataSetChanged()`
5. Call *this Activity* once again Using *Intent*.

here for Example: I take one list view `listVw` ->

```
holder.button.setText("End");
holder.button.setTag(position);
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // your needed stuffs...
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
});

  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Do your stuff here... 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to uses an instance of the [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) since that adapter has the remove method. Otherwise you will need to implement your own remove method and have you custom Adapter extend [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). Here is an example of what methods you need to call to remove an item from the list and tell the Adapter to refresh the list.

```
m_adapter.remove(o);
m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You want to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of `notifyDataSetInvalidated()`. Here is the difference ....

`notifyDataSetChanged()` - Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

`notifyDataSetInvalidated()` - Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data is no longer valid or available.